# What is the purpose of the increment statement?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, increment

Why are increment statements a thing in for-loops in C++?  To me it seems redundant, because you could simply put the increments inside the conditional code.  Am I misunderstanding something important here?

To illustrate my question better, I'm including some pseudocode:
What is the difference between ->

```
for( int a = 10; a < 20; a = a + 1 )
{
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

and

```
for( int a = 10; a < 20;)
{
    a = a + 1
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, the increment happens at the **end** of the loop body. Secondly, yes, `for` is (99%) just syntactic sugar; look it up as it's been discussed many times. Would you rather type the former or the latter? Many people find the former more convenient and easier to understand at-a-glance, and that's really all there is to it.

Comment: You could a use a `while` statement too. It just makes your code simple and more readable.

Comment: @underscore_d it's sugar, yes, but it's also idiomatic and probably good practice to follow.  Also, other languages will often not let you assign to a control loop variable so it helps to maintain a consistency of pattern in code-thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[ snips grumbling about quality of now deleted/ edited answers ;-) ]*

This:

```
for (unsigned counter = 1; counter <= 10; ++counter) {
    doStuff();
}
```

is *largely* equivalent to this:

```
unsigned counter = 1;
while (counter <= 10) {
    doStuff();
    ++counter;
}
```

with the notable exception that, in the 1st case, you have the considerable benefit that `counter` is scoped only to within the `for` block and automatically goes out-of-scope as soon as it finishes - whereas with the latter, `counter` must remain in-scope after the loop, where it's potentially useless or even an obstacle.

(tangential: Note that C did not support within-`for` declaration, or any non-top-of-block declarations, until C99 - but barring extenuating circumstances, anyone not using at least C99 by now is making a questionable choice imho.)

edit: Craig also makes a very good point regarding `continue` - an oft-forgotten but certainly useful statement. I'm sure there are probably other differences we could conjure up.

Comment: You might see folk doing things like `for (int i = 10; i--;)` as (a) the condition check, like most things, can have side-effects, (b) the 'increment/decrement' statement can be empty (or nonsensical), & (c) many assume counting down to 0 is always faster. The latter requires not realising CPUs have moved on since the (genuinely lovely) Z80 so it might not matter, optimising compilers exist & may make it count down _anyway_ - & with the hypothetical naive compiler, a postdecrement might well be a slowdown. Sometimes I use this for brevity, but I grew out of believing it matters to performance.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I copied your answer into Visual Studio and messed around with it (comparing debugger, output etc) for a while.  Here's my finished product:

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int account; account = 10000;
 cout << "Your starting balance is " << account << endl;
 int month = 1;
 for (account = 10000; account > 0; month += 1)
 {
  account *= 1.005;
  account -= 500;
  cout << "Your balance after " << month << " months is " << account << "." << endl;
 }
 int years; years = 0;
 int extra; extra = 0;
 years = (month - 1) / 12;
 extra = (month - 1) % 12;

 cout << "Your money will run out in " << years << " years and " << extra << " months" << endl;
 
}

Comment: ewww, I had no idea comments were formatted incorrectly for code.  Oh well.

Comment: You can apply `monospace` by enclosing in backticks, but yeah, linebreaks and whatnot get nixed. Can we get just get a summary of what your program showed you? :)

Comment: Your starting balance is 10000
Your balance after 1 months is 9549.
Your balance after 2 months is 9096.
...(etc)...
Your balance after 22 months is -451.
Your money will run out in 1 years and 10 months.


So the purpose was the total in my bank account, figure out monthly expenses, count interest over time, and then find out how long what I have will last.  I'm going to add in where I can enter in a custom starting amount, interest rate, and monthly cost while the program is running.

Answer (score 8):

It's more than mere convenience sometimes.

These are equivalent:

```
for (int a = 10; a < 20;  a = a + 1) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

for (int a = 10; a < 20;  ) {
    cout << a << endl;
    a = a + 1;
}
```

But, these are *not*:

```
// this works ...
for (int a = 10; a < 20;  a = a + 1) {
    if (blah ...)
        continue;
    cout << a << endl;
}

// this doesn't
for (int a = 10; a < 20;  ) {
    if (blah ...)
        continue;
    cout << a << endl;
    a = a + 1;
}
```

Since you're coming from python, an *idiomatic* for loop is like a python `range`, but much more powerful.  Your C for loop, expressed in python would be:

```
for a in range(10,20,1)
```

It's more idiomatic to express this as:

```
for (a = 10;  a < 20;  a += 1)
```

Because the loop increment is `1`, it's even *more* idiomatic to do this:

```
for (a = 10;  a < 20;  ++a)
```

But, for loops are:

```
for ([init_stmt];  [test_stmt];  [incr_stmt])
```

Where any of the *_stmt can be compound:

```
for (x = 0, y = 0;  x < 10;  ++x, y += 2)
```

Comment: Great example of a rare but useful nuance, which manually reinventing the wheel can't capture (without necessitating even more reinvention!), +1

Answer (score 4):

Convenience.

However, your equivalent code should be:

```
for (int a = 10; a < 20;)
{
    cout << a << endl;
    a = a + 1;
}
```

It runs at the end of the loop body.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer!  I come from a Python background and am just starting C++ so I was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

for this example:

```
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for( int a = 10; a < 20;)
       {
        a = a + 1;
        cout << a << endl;
   }


    return 0;
}
```

the output will be from 11-->20

the first example will be from 10-->19

your are putting the increment part outside the loop and this possible, but notice that the value 10 will not appear, because you are increment before printing the value of a
so in the 2nd example your printing the value and then increment, and at the end of the loop, you are quiting the loop without reaching 20, because the condition get you out the loop

[image: for loop process]

executing code block before increment is the key for you, the for loop increment just after the code block is executed

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not required, it is just for convenience.
In your second code, you made a little mistake which would make the code nonequivalent to the the first one.

Your increment should be at the end of loop in order to be equivalent to the first code
so it should rather be:

```
for( int a = 10; a < 20;)
{
cout << a << endl;
a = a + 1; //increment at the end of instructions
}
```

These little errors and also errors like forgetting to include your increment is why it is convenient to include the increment in the for loop.

Or you can use the while loop instead:

```
while (condition)
{//instructions here;}
```